# How to deserialize an XML with information about a custom object, using DataContract?

Tags: c#, xml, wcf, serialization

I was able to serialize a List of objects (List) using this code:

```
public static string Serialize(object obj)
{
    using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(memoryStream))
    {
        DataContractSerializer serializer = new DataContractSerializer(obj.GetType());
        serializer.WriteObject(memoryStream, obj);
        memoryStream.Position = 0;
        return reader.ReadToEnd();
    }
}
```

However, I'm not able to deserialize using this code:

```
public static object Deserialize(string xml, Type toType)
{
    using (Stream stream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        byte[] data = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(xml);
        stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
        stream.Position = 0;
        DataContractSerializer deserializer = new DataContractSerializer(toType);
        return deserializer.ReadObject(stream);
    }
}
```

I'm not able to understand the problem.
I'm using the last method by calling it with:

Deserialize(SerializedObject, List), but I'm getting an error saying `List<FilesToProcess> is a type, which is not valid in the given context`

Could anyone help? I'm a bit over my head with this.

Answer (score 0):

Sooo, I have the doubtful honor of answering my own question.

The problem was that I was trying to assign the output of

`public static object Deserialize(string xml, Type toType)`

to a List generic called listOfFiles, when I should have assigned to an object and then cast to a `List<FilesToProcess>` using

```
List<FilesToProcess listOfFiles = (List<FilesToProcess)listOfFilesObject;
```